# How to fix a segmentation fault error while accessing this next in linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, hashmap

I am a student learning data structures, attempting to implement a hashmap function that will add elements using nodes of a linked list. When I call to next value, I end up getting a segfault in my else statement, and I can not figure out why. Any help is appreciated, thank you all.

```
  void insertMap (struct hashMap * ht, KeyType k, ValueType v)
  {  /*write this*/
int idx = stringHash1(k);
struct hashLink * hlnk;
struct hashLink * plink;
assert(ht);

if(ht->table[idx] == NULL){
    hlnk = (struct hashLink *) malloc(sizeof(struct hashLink));
    hlnk->value = v;
    hlnk->key = k;
    hlnk->next = NULL;
    ht->table[idx] = hlnk;
    ht->count++;
}

else{
            plink = ht->table[idx];
            hlnk = (struct hashLink *) malloc(sizeof(struct hashLink));
            hlnk->value = v;
            hlnk->key = k;
            hlnk->next = plink->next;
            plink->next = hlnk;
            ht->count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Putting up the entire code is always helpful or if not the relevant definitions of the data structures and functions. 
We don't know the definition of struct hashMap, struct hashLink and similarly other function used by you. 
The error in the code could be anywhere.

Comment: Check that you have really set things to NULL initially. If you did not set all possible `ht->table[idx]`entries to NULL, it may happen that you end up in your `else` part when you really wanted to be in the first part of your if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert the node at the front of the list you need to update `ht->table[idx]` as well.

Currently you are updating local pointer `plink` in your `else` case.

```
else{
           .....
            plink->next = hlnk; //this line only updates the local pointer
            ht->count++;
    }
```

it should be

```
  else{
               .....
               ht->table[idx] = hlnk;
  }
```